# JavaScript integer storing as undefined for some reason

Tags: javascript, html

basically I have a number stored within my javascript structure, something like the following:

MyProgram.data.main.padding;

```
console.log(MyProgram.data.main.padding); // will output the number, something like 34.
```

However, I need to store that number in a struct I have set up in

```
MyProgram.data.tests.main.padding; // this is a struct  " {'width':0, 'padding':0, 'acceptable' //etc...}
```

The problem is when I do this:

```
MyProgram.data.tests.main.padding = MyProgram.data.main.padding;

console.log(MyProgram.data.tests.main.padding); // shows undefined
```

any ideas why I can't store the number?

I really appreciate any help...

Can someone load this example on jsfiddle please? I don't know how:
http://jsfiddle.net/hdnj52Lp/2/
RESULT OUTPUT ON MY LOCAL TEST: 0) acceptable: **true** fontSize **undefined** padding: **undefined**

```
    function MyProgram() {
var mp = this;

    this.main = {
        'data' : {
            'padding': 50,
            'fontSize': 10,
            'tests' : {
                'padding':null,
                'fontSize':null,
                'results':new Array()
            }
        },

        'test' : function () {
            console.log('running');
            var testResult = {'acceptable':false, 
                              'fontSize':0,
                              'padding':0} 

            //after some testing:
            var newComputedPadding = 100;
            var newComputedFontSize = 32;
            var acceptable = true;
            testResult.acceptable = acceptable;
            testResult.fontSize = newComputedFontSize;
            testResult.padding = newComputedPadding;

            mp.main.data.tests.results.push(testResult);
            mp.main.outputResults();
        },

        'outputResults' : function () {

            for(var i = 0; i < mp.main.data.tests.results.length; i++) {
                console.log( i + ') acceptable: ' + mp.main.data.tests.results[i].acceptable + ' fontSize ' + mp.main.data.tests.results.fontSize + ' paddingSides: ' + mp.main.data.tests.results.padding);
        }    
        }
    }

}


var Load;
if (window.attachEvent) {
 Load =function ( elem, event, handler ) {
      elem.attachEvent( 'on'+event, function load() { 
        handler();
        elem.detachEvent( 'on'+event, load );
     });
 };
} else {
 Load =function ( elem, event, handler ) {
    elem.addEventListener( event, function load() { 
        handler();
        elem.removeEventListener( event, load, false );
    }, false);
 };
}

Load(window, 'load', function() { 
var MP = new MyProgram();
MP.main.test();
});
```

Comment: What does it log when you do console.log(MyProgram.data.tests.main)

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors, and it logs: [object Object]

Comment: The weird thing is that the acceptable shows true as true when I set it to true, but the fontSize and padding show undefined...

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle or something. This is impossible to solve.

Comment: ok i will, i've never used jsfiddle so please give me a few minutes

Comment: lol...i dont know how to get it to load on jsfiddle.... I put a test together that should be the same as what my problem is, Can someone make it load on JS Fiddle? I'm posting it as an edit to my post

Comment: I figured out how to make it load, here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/hdnj52Lp/2/

Answer (score 2):

You are simply printing

```
mp.main.data.tests.results.fontSize
```

instead of

```
mp.main.data.tests.results[i].fontSize
```

The code is correct for `acceptable` but you forgot the `[i]` part for `fontSize` and `padding`.

Comment: RON2015: unfortunately in Javascript even a typo when accessing a field object doesn't raise an error, but just returns `undefined` and keeps on going. Sometimes this is apparently useful, but it's a step into the dark side... ;-)

Comment: Yes that's Javascript. You should read https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/ Good info there.